# Different types of tuners

Tags: tuner

I use a clip-on tuner on my guitar. I play a string. If the LCD display turns green, that string is in tune. Otherwise, it shows if it is too high or too low.

I saw someone else's tuner a few years ago. It would display the names of notes played to it. That person was using it to tune various instruments. If I remember correctly, I sang notes into that tuner and it would tell me what notes they were, not just the 6 guitar-strings notes, but any notes I could sing in a scale.

Those are two very different types of tuners. Do they have names? I would like to purchase one like the second one I described. I don't know what to ask for.

I am not certain if remember this correctly, so I would appreciate any help into identifying what I am talking about. Thank you!

Comment: Check out these: [**_Snark Tuners_**](https://www.sweetwater.com/c938--Snark--Guitar_Tuners) . They are designed mainly for guitar and bass, but from what I've seen, they will work for just about anything - they detect the sonic vibrations that resonate through an  instrument. I think some of them also have a mic. I've been using them for years to tune guitars, basses and harmonicas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some tuners will be configured for a specific instrument, and only show the notes that the instrument uses. For example a "violin only" tuner would only show the notes G D A E on the tuner.

Tuners that show every half step /  semitone are called chromatic tuners and give you the closest note name to pitch you are playing.

In some cases a tuner will have the ability to change settings to various instruments, or keep a chromatic list.

Besides physical tuners, there are apps for smartphones and tablets that will also provide tuning.

Comment: Chromatic is the word I was looking for, and I see my current tuner has a chromatic mode, aside from the guitar mode I have been using.

Comment: Good answer, from experience, a chromatic tuner will cost as small as $3 (AUD) online.

Comment: I also found the Boss Chromatic Tuner for free as an app for my phone.